# How does Benefactor's Armor interact with powers that provide healing over time?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items

The text on the Encounter power of Benefactors Armor states "Use this power when you use a healing power. Each ally healed by that power gains additional hit points equal to your Charisma modifier."

Now, say you apply that power to something like Stirring Shout ... does it grant the bonus to every ally healed by Stirring Shout over the course of the encounter?

Answer (score 1):

I'm inclined to say once.
4E tends to rely on being overtly specific with wording, and you have:

> **Each** ally **healed** by that power gains additional hit points equal to your Charisma modifier.

Rather than:

> **Each time** an ally is healed by that power, they regain additional hitpoints equal to your charisma modifier.

Though, ultimately it's up to the DM to make the final decision.
(though I admit it's terribly unlikely that a 4E item would take repeated/continual healing into account)

Comment: Fair enough and sensible enough, although parsing it like that would lead me to believe that each ally who was healed could benefit from the additional Charisma once over the encounter.

Comment: I don't disagree that it's down to bizarre legalistic pedantry. In practice, my group generally just tries to go with "Whatever seems the most balanced at the time".